# file upload problem in struts2

Tags: file, object, upload, struts2, dom

i want to upload a file and update result in other div on the same page dynamically just by showing a string "succeed/failed". It is working fine when i am forwarding result to a new page. However for below mentioned code  it is updating div id "two" to [object HTMLDocument]. Please show me the way to solve it.

```
<div id='two' style="border: 1px solid yellow;"><b>initial content</b></div>
<s:form id='theForm2' cssStyle="border: 1px solid green;" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='doUpload' method='post' theme="ajax">
<input type="file" name="upload" />
<s:submit value="GO2" theme="ajax" targets="two"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: you will need to show more code then this.... there is no javascript here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of file are you trying to upload?

For your action in your **struts.xml** file you need to have an action that has a result that is of **type="stream"**

```
<action name="myAction" class="com.MyJavaFileAction">

            <result name="SUCCESS" type="stream">

            <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
            <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${filename}"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>

            </result>
```